# Slater determinant in second quantization using the creation operators help

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, second-quantization

$$ 
\left\langle 0\left|\hat{\Psi}\left(x_{1}\right) c_{\alpha_{1}}^{\dagger}\right| 0\right\rangle=\left\langle 0\left|\varphi_{\alpha_{1}}\left(x_{1}\right)-c_{\alpha_{1}}^{\dagger} \hat{\Psi}\left(x_{1}\right)\right| 0\right\rangle=\varphi_{\alpha_{1}}\left(x_{1}\right)
 $$
$$ 
\left\langle 0\left|\hat{\Psi}\left(x_{1}\right) \hat{\Psi}\left(x_{2}\right) c_{\alpha_{2}}^{\dagger} c_{\alpha_{1}}^{\dagger}\right| 0\right\rangle=\left\langle 0\left|\hat{\Psi}\left(x_{1}\right)\left(\varphi_{\alpha_{2}}\left(x_{2}\right)-c_{\alpha_{2}}^{\dagger} \hat{\Psi}\left(x_{2}\right)\right) c_{\alpha_{1}}^{\dagger}\right| 0\right\rangle
 $$

$$ 
=\left\langle 0\left|\hat{\Psi}\left(x_{1}\right) c_{\alpha_{1}}^{\dagger}\right| 0\right\rangle \varphi_{\alpha_{2}}\left(x_{2}\right)-\left\langle 0\left|\hat{\Psi}\left(x_{1}\right) c_{\alpha_{2}}^{\dagger} \hat{\Psi}\left(x_{2}\right) c_{\alpha_{1}}^{\dagger}\right| 0\right\rangle
 $$

$$ 
=\varphi_{\alpha_{1}}\left(x_{1}\right) \varphi_{\alpha_{2}}\left(x_{2}\right)-\varphi_{\alpha_{2}}\left(x_{1}\right) \varphi_{\alpha_{1}}\left(x_{2}\right)
 $$

I'm trying to do this but the reason why
$$ 
c_{\alpha_{1}}^{\dagger} \hat{\Psi}\left(x_{1}\right)
 $$

is zero eludes me, especially since in N=2 it's not

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of question. Please don't post images of text. It breaks search functionality and won't work for blind people.

Comment: Remade it in LaTex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s because the single $\Psi$ is expanded into a sum of creation and annihilation operators $\sim a + a^\dagger$, and so you just have $\langle 0 | c^\dagger a_p | 0 \rangle$ and $\langle 0| c^\dagger a^\dagger_p |0 \rangle$, both of which are zero because the creation operator $c^\dagger$ hits the vacuum on the left.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. Ψ here is the field operator, even if I expand it I don't see how I get the second and third row from (25).